# Array sorting Angular 2

Tags: angular, google-chrome, sorting, typescript, angular5

In order to display data in the right order I have to sort my Array from a JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "totals": [
      {
        "start_time": "2018-02-26 06:00",
        "end_time": "2018-02-26 15:45",
        "date": "2018-02-26"
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2018-02-27 06:00",
        "end_time": "2018-02-27 15:30",
        "date": "2018-02-27"
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2018-02-28 03:00",
        "end_time": "2018-02-28 16:15",
        "date": "2018-02-28"
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2018-03-01 03:00",
        "end_time": "2018-03-01 15:45",
        "date": "2018-03-01"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is quite simplified though. I want to display the array inside totals sorted on date. I am doing this after fetching the data as follows:

```
    this.apiService.get('date').subscribe((result) => {
        this.result = result['totals']['data'];
        setTimeout(() => {this.sortMe(); }, 1);
    }

    sortMe(){    
        this.result.sort((a,b) => {
            return a.date.localeCompare(b.date)
        });
    }
```

I have to put it in a timeout function for it to work, but I don't know why that works. It is far from ideal.
The user sees the data displayed in the wrong order for a fraction of a second and then sees it ordered. 
It also does not work when I put it in a promise like so:

```
this.sortMe(unsorted).then( 
                (v) => {this.result = v}
            );

sortMe(unsorted){

    unsorted.sort((a,b) => {
        return a.date.localeCompare(b.date)
    });

    return Promise.resolve(unsorted);

}
```

I am still learning Angular, and I feel like there is something I am not getting here. Could it also be that there is something wrong with my JSON which is why Chrome (and perhaps other browsers) are picking it up like this?

Thank you for reading (:

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small example for you. 
Check it out and if you have any questions do not hesitate to ask.

Keep in mind that the sort function is for dates descending.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      data
      <pre>{{data | json}}</pre> sortedData
      <pre>{{sortedData | json}}</pre>
  </div>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data = {
    "data": {
      "totals": [
        {
          "start_time": "2018-02-26 06:00",
          "end_time": "2018-02-26 15:45",
          "date": "2018-02-26"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "2018-02-27 06:00",
          "end_time": "2018-02-27 15:30",
          "date": "2018-02-27"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "2018-02-28 03:00",
          "end_time": "2018-02-28 16:15",
          "date": "2018-02-28"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "2018-03-01 03:00",
          "end_time": "2018-03-01 15:45",
          "date": "2018-03-01"
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  sortedData = null;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    Observable.of(this.data.data.totals)
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.sortedData = [{}, ...x];
        this.sortedData.sort(this.compareFunction);
      });
  }

  compareFunction(a, b) {
    if (a.date > b.date) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.date < b.date) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

### UPDATE 1

Try something like this instead of your subscribe method:

```
this.apiService.get('date').subscribe(result => {
  this.sortedData = [{}, ...result];
  this.sortedData.sort(this.compareFunction);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I thought it was working but unfortunately, it seems like Chrome still has a problem with it. Could it be that my object/array has 28 items and Chrome sorts differently when there are 10+ items? When I put the code above the outcome is the same as when I don’t sort at all :(.

Comment: can you try with the update? You will need some similar logic to that one

Comment: Hello Igor, thanks for your update. I was away for the easterweekend so I tested it just now. I removed everything from my subscribe and replaced it with the above, but unfortunately still no sorting. It only seems to work with a setTimeout(). May I ask what the line this.sortedData = [{}, ...result]; does?

Comment: Sure, checkout this article. It explains all usages. If you are interested only in **Array Assignment** read only that topic. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/spread-operator.html